# Widget of context in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't understand what does Widget.of(context) work and what one is in Flutter. When use one? What's a BuildContext exactly?

````
....
)

return IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Icons.add),
   onPressed() {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)
   }
),```
````

Comment: does it find the Scaffold widget and insert into Scaffold the snackBar? Why I can not just enter the SnackBar straightforward in Scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

Widget.of() gets the nearest Widget in the widget tree. It traverses up in the tree (via Context) and looks for a Widget. Scaffold in your example. Or more detailed the nearest Scaffold from the IconButton upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to show a `snackbar`, `Scaffold` is the widget that knows how to draw a `snackbar` so first, you need to get the Scaffold of your widget and then tell it to show `snackbar`, this can be done by using `.of()`.

`.of()` returns the State of the inherited widget. By using `Scaffold.of(context)` you are trying to get the state of Scaffold widget at higher level of your widget tree.

[This](https://flutterbyexample.com/build-context-class/) article has some good explanation of the .of() function and what exactly is BuildContext.